# Get all public albums of a Facebook user profile - iOS Facebook SDK

Tags: objective-c, facebook, public, photos

Is there a way to get all public albums of a user profile in Facebook? For example if I use my app *access_token* in a URL like this:

> https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/albums?access_token=MY_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

I get this error:

```
{
"error": 
{
  "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 102
}
}
```

Why? Is it the right syntax?

After solving that, How can I do it in Objective-C?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you want to get the public albums of a user, you need to ask the user to grant the correct permission and login with your application. `user_photos` is required to see the current user's photos, and `friends_photos` is required to see the user's friends' photos.

Comment: Can I do the login programmatically using username and password or FB Connect is the only way?

Comment: FB Connect is the only way. You are forbidden from asking the user for their facebook username / password. And even if you had them, you cannot use them to access the API.

Answer (score 0):

Had encountered this issue recently. Edit the permission of app in Facebook developers website. Adding `user_photos` in `User & Friend permissions` fixed my problem.